# Merging rows based on 3 columns (duplicates) & summing another

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge duplicates in this data frame in R

```
first last  city    in   out   
john  doe   sf      1    0
mary  jane  cl      0    1 
john  doe   sf      1    0
mary  jane  cl      1    0 
john  shmo  dn      1    0
```

to this result

```
john  doe   sf    2    0
mary  jane  cl    1    1 
john  shmo  dn    1    0
```

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `mydf %>% group_by(first, last, city) %>% summarize(in = sum(in), out = sum(out)) %>% ungroup()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to shift Phil's answer from the comment to a actual answer. Using `dplyr` is probably the easiest way to solve the problem.

```r
mydf %>% group_by(first, last, city) %>% 
summarize(in = sum(in), out = sum(out)) %>% 
ungroup()
```

Just don't forget the `ungroup` command. Neglecting that can lead to some nasty surprises later.

Comment: what if the data has character data like the city that also needs to replace the NA?
first last  city    in   out   
john  doe   sf      1    0
mary  jane  cl      0    1 
john  doe   NA      1    0
mary  jane  NA      1    0 
john  shmo  dn      1    0